# pass a <script> from domain B to domain A

Tags: javascript, php

I'm building a Remote Url upload to a different server with a progressbar, 
now I have this 2 domains, namely domain A and B

I want to upload the remote url file from domain A to domain B, I have a php function in domain B to echo **< script>parentFunction(); < /script>** in domain A,

I know this is not possible in any browser because of security issues but I just want to ask if there is a workaround for this

this is my php code in **Domain B** if anybody needs

```
function upload(url)
{
if ( function_exists( 'stream_context_create' ) )
    {
            $httpArr = array(
                'timeout' => 15, // 15 seconds
                );

            $httpArr[ 'notification' ] = [ $this, 'remote_url_progress_callback' ];

            $ctx = stream_context_create();
                stream_context_set_params( $ctx, $httpArr );
    }
}


function remote_url_progress_callback( $notification_code, $severity, $message, $message_code, $bytes_transferred, $bytes_max )
    {
        switch($notification_code) {
            case STREAM_NOTIFY_RESOLVE:
            case STREAM_NOTIFY_AUTH_REQUIRED:
            case STREAM_NOTIFY_FAILURE:
            case STREAM_NOTIFY_AUTH_RESULT:
            break;

            case STREAM_NOTIFY_COMPLETED:
            echo '<script>parent.remoteProgress( '. json_encode( array( 'loaded' => $bytes_max, 'total' => $bytes_max ) ) .');</script>';
            break;

            case STREAM_NOTIFY_REDIRECTED:
            break;

            case STREAM_NOTIFY_CONNECT:
            echo '<script>parent.rstartTime = (new Date()).getTime();</script>';
            break;

            case STREAM_NOTIFY_FILE_SIZE_IS:
            echo '<script>parent.remoteProgress( '. json_encode( array( 'loaded' => 0, 'total' => $bytes_max ) ) .');</script>';
            break;

            case STREAM_NOTIFY_MIME_TYPE_IS:
            break;

            case STREAM_NOTIFY_PROGRESS:
            echo '<script>parent.remoteProgress( '. json_encode( array( 'loaded' => $bytes_transferred, 'total' => $bytes_max ) ) .');</script>';
            break;
        }
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
```

This is my code in **domain A**

```
function remoteProgress( value )
{
    var percentageDone = parseInt( value.loaded / value.total * 100, 10 );
    nowTime = ( new Date() ).getTime();
    loadTime = ( nowTime - rstartTime );

    if ( loadTime == 0 )
    {
        loadTime = 1;
    }

    loadTimeInSec = loadTime / 1000
    bytesPerSec = value.loaded / loadTimeInSec;

    var textContent = '';
    textContent += 'Progress: '+percentageDone+'%';
    textContent += ' ';
    textContent += '('+bytesToSize(value.loaded, 2)+' / '+bytesToSize(value.total, 2)+')';
    textContent += '<br />Speed: '+ bytesToSize( bytesPerSec, 2 ) +'/s. ';

    progressText = textContent;
    $( '#remote-progress-bar' ).css( 'display', 'inline-block' );
    $( '#remote-progress-bar .bar').css(
        'width',
        percentageDone + '%'
    );

    $( '#remote-progress-text' ).html(progressText);
}
```

// domain is just dummy

```
$( '#remote-upload-progresser' ).prop( 'src', 'http://123.123.122.199/test/fileshare/remote/do-remote-upload/?remote[url_files]='+ encodeURIComponent( remote_files.join( "@@BREAK@@@" ) )  );
```

Comment: If you have control over both domains, everything is possible without security issues.

Comment: I have control over the two domains, my problem is in the browser itself im having this error.

Error permission denied to access property from domain B to domain A

Comment: Using CORS should be the simplest solution. However, if you need further help, please also show the code of domain A. I'm still not sure what exactly you want to do, and what errors you are getting.

Comment: I already added the code sir from my Domain A, is that enough?

Whenever I start uploading the browser gives me this error
this is the error "Error: Permission denied to access property remoteProgress"


@Bergi
I've already searched for a solution or workaround but I failed to see the answer. I'm desperate to solve this, I've been on this for like 2 weeks without progress. Thanks for taking the time to look at it :)

Comment: so your domain B page is embedded as an iframe in your domain A page? That's the part of the picture I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access external JavaScript on two different site, you'll need to add a CORS header, which looks like the following:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

It's not clear what exactly you're trying to achieve, but to enable this, you can add a `header()` function call to your PHP code.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

If you'd only like to allow external JavaScript from Domain A on Domain B, you can modify the string to:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domainA.com");
```

Remember to put the header call before any content is delivered to the client (i.e. before any `echo` statment)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the headers is already setup, but its still not working.

I am trying to fetch the progress of my remote URL upload thru another server